# How to identify a process in Windows? Kernel and User mode

Tags: windows, process, kernel, access-control

In Windows, what is the formal way of identifying a process uniquely? I am not talking about PID, which is allocated dynamically, but a unique ID or a name which is permanent to that process. I know that every program/process has a security descriptor but it seems to hold SIDs for loggedin user and group (not the process). We cannot use the path and name of executable from where the process starts as that can change.

My aim is to identify a process in the kernel mode and allow it to perform certain operation. What is the easiest and best way of doing this?

Comment: I don't think there is a unique identifier in quite the way you mean, though I believe the process ID will remain unique so long as the process object exists (even if the process has exited).  The best way of allowing a particular process to perform a particular operation depends on what the operation is, but I suppose the simplest generic solution is to provide one or more IOCTLs; the device driver can perform any security checks it likes before taking the appropriate action on behalf of the user-mode process.

Comment: Keep in mind that restricting access to a particular process rather than particular users does not provide much additional security, because the user that owns the process (or any administrator) can insert foreign code easily enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and sorry for the delayed response) :)  What I intend to do is uniquely identify a binary. If the binary is moved around on the storage to different paths, I should still be able to identify it. Some sort of ID built directly into it so that normal users cannot change it. This helps in identifying say, certain third party developers, or even in house binaries.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too vague to answer properly. For example *how* could the path possibly change (without poking around in kernel memory) *after* creation of a process? And yes, I am aware that one could hook into the memory-mapping process during process creation to replace the image originally destined to be loaded with another. Point is that a process is merely one instance of running a given executable. And it's not clear what exact tampering attempts you want to counter here.

But from kernel mode you *do* have the ability to simply use the pointer to the [`EPROCESS` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544273.aspx). No need to use the PID, although that will be unique *while* the process is still alive.

So assuming your process uses an IRP to communicate to the driver (whether it be `WriteFile`, `ReadFile`, `DeviceIoControl` or something more exotic), in order to register itself, you can use [`IoGetCurrentProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549177.aspx) to get the `PEPROCESS` value which will be *unique* to the process.

While the structure itself is not officially documented, hints can be gleaned from the "Windows Internals" book (in its various incarnations), the `dt` (Display Type) command in WinDbg (and friends) as well as from third-party resources on the internet (e.g. [here, specific to Vista](http://www.nirsoft.net/kernel_struct/vista/EPROCESS.html)).

The process objects are kept in several linked lists. So if you know the (officially undocumented!!!) layout for a particular OS version, you may traverse the lists to get from one to the next process object (i.e. `EPROCESS` structure).

#### Cautionary notes

Make sure to reference the object of the process, by using the respective object manager routines. Otherwise you cannot be certain it's safe to both reach into these structures (which is anyway unsafe, since you cannot rely on their layout across OS versions) or to pass it to functions that expect a `PEPROCESS`.

As a side-note: Harry Johnston is of course right to assert that a privileged user can insert arbitrary (well almost arbitrary) code into the TCB in order to thwart your protective measures. In the end it is going to be an arms race.

Also keep in mind that similar to PIDs, theoretically the value of the `PEPROCESS` may be recycled. But in both cases you can simply counter this by invalidating whatever internal state you keep in your driver that allows the process to do its magic, whenever the process goes down. Using something like [`PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559951.aspx) would seem to be a good method here. In order to translate your process handle from the callback to a `PEPROCESS` value, use `ObReferenceObjectByHandle`.

An alternative of countering recycling of the PID/`PEPROCESS` is by keeping a reference to the process object and thus keeping it in a kind of undead state (similar to not closing a handle in user mode), although the main thread may have finished.